# How to navigate to new page from TextInput field?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[In this form i want to navigate to the new page as i click on the  Field of Primary Address and Primary Bank Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFkor.png)
[In this form i want to navigate to new page conatining another form as i click on the  field of primary address or primary bank account.]

```
<Text style={styles.labels}>
                        Address:
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput 
                        style={styles.textinput}
                        placeholder="Primary Address"
                        placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                        mode="outlined"
                        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />

                    <Text style={styles.labels}>
                        Bank Account:
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput 
                        style={styles.textinput}
                        placeholder="Primary Bank Account"
                        placeholderTextColor="#000000"
                        mode="outlined"
                        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} />
```

Comment: can you post your complete code ?

Comment: If you are using a navigation library like react-navigation then try this.On TextInput's onFocus={()=>navigation.navigate('newpage')}

Answer (score 0):

Use ONFOCUS like
 `onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }

onFocus() {
     },`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a `TouchableOpacity` and take the user to next page using `onPress`

Also set `editable` prop to `false` in `TextInput`.